# No `render` method found on the returned component instance

Tags: javascript, react-native, console.log

I have initialized the basic react-native app by the command `react-native init DummyProject` and try to compile and run it. but its giving me an error on debug console

```
Warning: AppContainer(...): No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render`.
```

and

```
TypeError: instance.render is not a function

This error is located at:
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
```

The code and error my application is in this picture
[image: The code and error my application is in this picture]

I am experiencing this error even after removing node_modules and again installing the modules.
Making another app won't work either. Same error is occurring in every situation

The code of my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: 1
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>HELLO {this.state.value}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import App from "./App";
import { name as appName } from "./app.json";

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "DummyProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.1",
    "react-native": "0.57.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.49.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide codes as text inline to your question, not an image of it

Comment: is this all the code you have on your app? i just ran it and it works.. do you have a class named AppContainer?

Comment: Which RN version you are using ?

Comment: No @kivul I don't have any class named AppContainer

Comment: @LastBreath I am using `"react-native": "0.57.5"`

Comment: Having same problem here...

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it work perfectly fine for me.

Maybe you are facing a cache issue, Try this: Delete the `node_modules` folder and close the packager. Then reinstall using the command `npm install` from your project directory.

After this try running your code again. It should work.

Comment: I already mentioned it, that removing node_modules and reinstalling them didn't fix the issue